# Call a block on multiple UIViewController variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I have a block which is called on one of my classes:

```
__weak BContactsViewController * weakSelf = self;

_searchViewController.usersSelected = ^(NSArray * users) {
    // Do something
};
```

I am now creating another UIViewController that contains contains different functionality (adding users from social media search) but also returns users to be added to the app.

Although I could repeat this code for my second vc this solution wouldn't scale well if I was increasing the number of vc'. For this reason I am attempting to use the following code:

```
UIViewController * vc = type == bSearchTypeNameSearch ? _searchViewController : _customSearchViewController;

__weak UIViewController * weakSelf = self;

vc.userSelected = ^(NSArray * users) {

    // Do something 
};
```

Both view controllers would have the block code inside them so would be able to return and call the code I want.

This code though creates the error:

```
Property 'userSelected' not found on object type 'UIViewController'
```

I don't know if something like this is even possible. I have searched Google and Stackoverflow but it is very difficult to articulate the problem and there appears to be very little detailing something like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"? Have you set a breakpoint inside your block?  Is it ever executed?

Comment: @Paulw11 this code currently doesn't let the code compile due to an error, I have edited the question to provide more information on the error

Comment: That message tells you that `UIViewController` doesn't have a `userSelected` property.  You need to use a common UIViewController subclass for your two view controllers and have that subclass implement the `userSelected` property.  Then you can use this subclass instead of `UIViewController` in your ternary statement